# R - Optimize X, such that min(sum(X_i)) for all n, where X_n + X_(n-1) + X_(n-2) >= Y_n, where Y is known for all n

Tags: r, optimization, vector, lag, inequality

I have a unknown vector X with length=50, and a known vector Y (length 50) of constants.

I wish to find X, such that for X_i>=0, sum(X_i) is minimized, with the constraint:

X_n + X_{n-1} >= Y_n

I am not sure where to start with R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can try `CVXR` to solve the optimization problem.

1. First of all, let's define a matrix `M` like below

```
M <- matrix(0,nrow = 10,ncol = 11)
for (i in 1:nrow(M)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(M)) {
    if (j %in% (i+(0:1))) M[i,j] <- 1
  }
}
```

which looks like

```
> M
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
 [1,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 [2,]    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 [3,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0     0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0     0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0     0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0     0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1     0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     1     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1     1
```

2. Then, we construct the objective function as well as the constraints

```
library(CVXR)
X <- Variable(11)
objective <- Minimize(sum(X))
constraints <- list( X>=0, M%*%X >= Y)
problem <- Problem(objective,constraints)
res <- solve(problem)
```

3. Finally, we can see values of `X` via `res$getValue(X)`

---

**Example**
Given `Y` as below

```
set.seed(1)
Y <- runif(10)
```

we can get

```
Xopt <- res$getValue(X)

> Xopt
              [,1]
 [1,] 1.667850e-07
 [2,] 3.072356e-01
 [3,] 6.488860e-02
 [4,] 6.214644e-01
 [5,] 2.867441e-01
 [6,] 1.486883e-02
 [7,] 8.835218e-01
 [8,] 7.476340e-02
 [9,] 5.860353e-01
[10,] 5.264372e-02
[11,] 9.142897e-03
```

---

Another possible option might be `pracma::fmincon`, e.g.,

```
pracma:: fmincon(rep(0, 11),
  function(x) sum(x),
  A = -M,
  b = -Y,
  lb = 0,
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be expressed as a linear program

```
min 1'x
s.t. Ax >= y
     x >= 0
```

We can use the lpSolve package to solve this.   Let n be the length of x and k be the number of x's in each constraint. The constraints defined in the body of the question corresponds to k=2 but the subject of the question defines the constraints differently and corresponds to k=3. There will be n-k+1 constraints.

`embed(1:n,k)` creates an n-k+1 by k matrix each row of which is the column indexes of the ones in the corresonding row of A.  For example, for k=2 the first row of `embed(...)` is 1:2 since elements 1 and 2 of the first row of `A` are ones and the rest of the row of A is zeros.  The second row of `embed` output is 2:3, the third row is 3:4, etc. We then apply replace over the rows to replace an n-vector of zeros, `numeric(n)`, with ones in those positions.  The way apply works is that it gives the transpose of what we want so we transpose it back to get `A`.

Finally we run the linear program.  We can use `str(out)` to examine the output components that are returned.  In particular we display the solution as `out$solution`.

```
library(lpSolve)

# inputs - replace these three with your inputs
n <- 5 # no of x variables
k <- 2 # no of x's in each constraint
Y <- seq_len(n - k + 1)

A <- t(apply(embed(1:n, k), 1, replace, x = numeric(n), values = 1))
out <- lp("min", rep(1, n), A, ">=", Y)
out
## Success: the objective function is 6 

out$solution
## [1] 0 2 0 4 0
```